# IBM Cloud AppID with w3ID: Redirect URI 500 error with CloudFoundry application

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-appid

I've had this issue for weeks and still can't find any way to solve.
I've built a node.js application that is built upon the sample that is provided when setting up CloudFoundry.

My application is connected to AppID and uses IBMid authentication. My redirect URI is registered in my application code, in the AppID console and also registered with IBM IT security.

[image: AppID console image 1]
[image: AppID console image 2]

However when I navigate to my application, I am able to sign in with IBMid but then I get a 500 error for my redirect uri:

[image: browser 500 error]

I haven't been able to find a solution to the problem, nor are the Cloud Foundry and AppID documents helping.

Any guidance would be much appreciated!

Comment: Update: I tried with another authentication method (Google) and the same 500 error appeared.

Comment: Do you mean IBMid or w3ID? Anything IBM-internal or confidential...? :)

Comment: Have you registered the app's redirect URI in AppID? AppID redirects back to the app and that URI needs to be registered